# php применение if elseif else в функции. Ошибка при сравнении данных

Tags: php, php7

Есть функция:

```
function findSimple($a, $b)
{
    $myArray = array();

    if($b > $a)
        for ($i = $a; $i < $b + 1; $i++) $myArray[] = $i;
    elseif($a == $b)
        $myArray[] = $a;
    else
        for ($j = $b; $j > $a - 1; $j--) $myArray[] = $j;

    return $myArray;
}//function findSimple($a, $b)
```

Вызываю функцию три раза с разными значениями параметров:

```
      try {
            print_r(findSimple(2, 2));   //func.php
            echo "</br>";
            print_r(findSimple(2, 10));   //func.php
            echo "</br>";
            print_r(findSimple(10, 2));   //func.php
       } catch (Exception $ex)
       {
           $msg = $ex->getMessage();
           $line = $ex->getLine();
           echo "<span class='red-text'>$msg</span> в строке $line";
       } // try-catch
```

Результат:

Array ( [0] => 2 )
 Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 6 [5] => 7 [6] => 8 [7] => 9 [8] => 10 )
 Array ( )

Вопрос: Почему при аргументе a > b (третий вызов функции) массив пустой?

Comment: Вы  вот это так сложно хотите написать?  - `range($a,$b);`

Comment: Это тестовое задание, по условию я не должен использовать стандартные функции

Comment: на всяксий случай `$result = range(...($a < $b ? [$a, $b] : [$b, $a]));`

Comment: или `range(min($a, $b). max($a,$b))`

Comment: хотя похоже вам там надо, просто убывающий ряд то просто `range()` без всяких изысков

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте внимательно `"$j = $b; $j > $a - 1; $j--"` и что вы передаёте в третьем вызове функции... Идём по порядку. `$a = 10; $b = 2; $j = $b то есть 2; $j (2) > $a - 1 (9)` итог: в условии 2 больше 9. Всё работает правильно. Цикл по этому и не выполняется, соответственно и массив пустой, так как переменная $myArray заполняется в цикле.